# Destroy a single particle in Phaser.js

Tags: phaser-framework

How I can destroy a single particle using phaser.js?, currently I have a simple particle system in my game (using a image as particle). I have seen the phaser documentation and the `destroy` function destroys all particle system (I want to destroy only one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Phaser.Emitter` extends `Phaser.Group`, you can iterate over the children elements of an Emitter with the methods you have available for a group (and the ones specific to an Emitter - look [here](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.1/Phaser.Particles.Arcade.Emitter.html#methods) - you have `getFirstAlive()` for example).

So you can have it like this:

```
emitter.getFirstAlive().destroy();
```

but it's up to you to find the one specific particle you want to destroy.

Comment: Thanks @Kamen your answer was useful for me